# About assumptions in the monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Why is the hypothesis that $\left\{f_n \right\}$ be an increasing sequence essential to the monotone convergence theorem? Could someone provide a nice, easy to understand counterexample if I were to assume otherwise? Thank you.

Comment: Are you just looking for a sequence such that $\int \lim f_n$ is not $\lim \int f_n$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. _

Comment: It the fact that the convention $0 \cdot \infty$ implies multiplication is upward continiuous. Thus the luck of symmetry. And notice all these theorems(about convergence), start inductively from multiplication, then going to simple functions then going limits of simple function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take for instance $f_n = \frac{1}{n}$, $f_n$ are deacreasing.

Then $\lim _{ n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty } f_n(x) \rm{d}x = \infty$

But $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty }\lim _{ n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) \rm{d}x =0$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample where $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ still converges a.e. to $f$: take $f=0$ and $f_{n}=n\mathbf{1}_{[0,n^{-1}]}$ on $[0,1]$. Then $f_{n}\to f$ everywhere but $0$, but $\int_{[0,1]}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$ while $\int_{[0,1]}f_{n}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Requiring $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to increase to $f$ prevents this kind of behavior (since all functions are assumed nonnegative).